# How to store votes of many polls in a cookie in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I am developing a voting poll plugin for WordPress. In my voting poll I am trying to add some restriction method for avoiding multiple vote, such as restriction via IP and restriction via cookie. I have created restriction via IP.

But now I am trying to add restriction via cookie. I know its an easy process. But my problem is user could add unlimited poll in widget or post. As far I know, from a single website browser can save 20 cookies.

That means if I add 20 polls, it will create 20 cookies. If admin creates more than 20 polls, it needs more than 20 cookies. As a result it won't work.

Please inform me what can I do in this situation.

Comment: You can save more than `1 unit of information` per cookie. for example by using `serialize()` or `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all polls in a single cookie by using base64-encoded JSON serialization.

Let's assume you have votes for polls stored in an array:

```
$polls = array(
   1 => 1,
   2 => 2,
   3 => 3
);
```

You can write these in a single cookie with:

```
setcookie('polls', base64_encode(json_encode($polls)));
```

And similarly you can read the from the cookie with:

```
$polls = json_decode(base64_decode($_COOKIE['polls']));
```